# Schoenfeld's limits & almost primes

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers

If I am correct in my understanding, the Tao-Green theorem employed almost primes as density normalisers. If $N_k(x)$ is the counting function of almost primes, is the study of almost primes 'useful' in studying the limits of primes (eg Schoenfeld's explicit limit of $|\pi(x)-\rm {li}(x)|\le \frac {1}{8\pi}\sqrt {x}\log (x)\text { for all }x \geq 2657
$)? In other words, is the study of  large $k$ commutable to the study of $k=1$, or is it too inexact?